# How do I change image on hover of <td> that the img is in - in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

You can see the implementation here http://jsfiddle.net/xNSFA/

Right now, when you hover over the cell, it changes some of the characteristics. But the image doesn't change. The image only changes when you hover over the image specifically.

How do I get the image to change with everything else?

By the way, it doesn't HAVE to be done in jQuery. If there is a nice elegant way to do this in CSS, I would love that. But I just assumed it was impossible to do - because of the image manipulation and I didn't want to set the background of the  to be that image. I want the image inside the cell.

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't notice that you didn't want to use background images. You can still do it with CSS, but would need to change the markup to include both images. Not sure if that's an acceptable solution for you. Anyway, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) on the `<td>` and find the `<img>` inside to change, like this:

```
$("table td").hover(function() {
  var img = $(this).find("img")[0];
  img.src = img.src.replace('-grey.png', '-blk.png');
}, function() {
  var img = $(this).find("img")[0];
  img.src = img.src.replace('-blk.png', '-grey.png');
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Ce7DK/), or the jQuery-ish way (though slower - some prefer it...I'd go with the above):

```
$("table td").hover(function() {
  $(this).find("img").attr("src", function(i, src) {
    return src.replace('-grey.png', '-blk.png'); 
  });
}, function() {
  $(this).find("img").attr("src", function(i, src) {
    return src.replace('-blk.png', '-grey.png');
  });
});
```

Comment: I used the top one. Thanks. But quick question, you said the 'jQuery-ish' way....so what's the top way? Just Javascript way? But if I am not mistaken, isn't $() the jQuery ready() selector ? Just wondering why you did two versions, when as far as I know, the top one is using jQuery selectors too.

Comment: @marcamillion - I mean jquery-ish as in accessing all your attributes in a consistent way (`.attr()` for example), it's certainly not needed...and not preferred by me, I want the most efficient access possible; you can't beat a DOM property there.

Comment: Ahh...I see. Ok cool. That's what I thought, but just wanted confirmation. Thanks. P.S. I agree with you, with preferring DOM properties. Much more elegant and quicker - imo.

Answer (score 4):

**New answer:** *I didn't notice that you didn't want to use a background image. It can be done without, but you would just need to load both images.*

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/xNSFA/7/

*html*

```
<td>
    <span class="sit-in-the-corner">1</span>
    <img class="on" src="http://fiwishop.com/feedback/images/2-up-icon-blk.png" />
    <img class="off" src="http://fiwishop.com/feedback/images/2-up-icon-grey.png" />
</td>
```

*css*

```
table td img.off{
    display:none;
}
table td:hover img.off{
    display:inline;
}
table td:hover img.on{
    display:none;
}
```

---

**Original answer:**

I'd use CSS instead of javascript, but you'll need to change the `<img>` element to an `<a>` element, and use the `background-` properties.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/xNSFA/5/

*html*

```
<td>
    <span class="sit-in-the-corner">1</span>
    <a class='image'></a>
</td>
```

*css*

```
table td a.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image:url(http://fiwishop.com/feedback/images/2-up-icon-blk.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    display:block;
}
table td a.image:hover {
    background-image:url(http://fiwishop.com/feedback/images/2-up-icon-grey.png);
}
```

Comment: You should note this layout behaves differently, since it requires the `<a>` to fill the entire cell now, rather then an area only the size of the image like the `<img>` did, insert any other content in to see what I mean.

Comment: @Nick: Certainly would depend on the markup. Changes could alter it. If IE6 support isn't needed, I'd just place the `background-image` on the `<td>`. Another possibility may be to use `absolute` positioning on the `<a>` if IE6 support is required. Anyway, I'd use CSS if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
td:hover img {
     //css attributes to change
}
```

OR to change the source

```
$("table td").hover(function() {                
                 this.src = $('img', this).src.replace('-grey.png', '-blk.png');
                }, function() {
                 this.src = $('img', this).src.replace('-blk.png', '-grey.png');                              
    });
```

The image source can't be changed via CSS, but you can change the background image, or background position.

Comment: Your code would blow up for a few reasons, `this.src` is the `src` of the `<td>`, which doesn't exist, and jQuery objects have no `src` property either :)

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
$('td').hover(
  function(){
    $(this).find('img').attr('src','path/to/new/image.png');
  },
  function(){
    $(this).find('img').attr('src','path/too/old/image.png');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues in your script.  First, you need to attach the hover to the `<td>`, not the `<img>` itself.  If you run your test, you'll see that the image *does* change when leaving the actual image.  Second, you seem to have your replaces reversed, so that the image first changes when you *leave* the hover area.

[Here's a version of your script with both changes.](http://jsfiddle.net/xNSFA/2/).  I think this is doing what you wanted?